# Transpose N rows with different columns into single column

Tags: text-processing

My data sample seems:

```
1 2 3 4 5
4 5 6 7 9 9 0
1 2 3 4
1 8 7 6 9
```

and I want to change in to :

```
1
2
3
4
5
4
5
6
7
9
9
0
1
2
3
4
1
8
7
6
9
```

Comment: yes u r right this is a sample data.

Comment: Dear Mr. Roaima, would you format it  with ur comment

Answer (score 3):

If input lines **doesn't have spaces** use this:

```
fold -1 data_sample.txt
```

> **fold** - wrap each input line to fit in specified width.

In this case the width is the one column, specified by `-1` option.

If input **has spaces**, but you want omit them, use this:

```
grep -o '\S' data_sample.txt
```

`\S` - matches any non-white-space character.

`-o` - print every matched parts on a separate line.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `rs` (reshape) utility:

```
$ rs 0 1 < data
1
2
3
4
5
4
5
6
7
9
9
0
1
2
3
4
1
8
7
6
9
```

The output array shape is determined from the optional `row` and `col` arguments as follows:

```
If only one of them is a positive integer, rs computes a value for the 
other which will accommodate all of the data.
```

In this case, `0` is not a positive integer, so the number of rows is chosen to put all the fields in a single column.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tr` command as follows:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < infile
```

and here are other options to do that.

```
sed -e $'s/\s*/\\\n/g' infile
```

Or:

```
sed 's/\s*/\
/g' infile.txt
```

Or in some `sed` implementations, use:

```
sed 's/\s*/\n/g' infile
```

Or via `gawk` (if you don't mind last empty line):

```
awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]*' '1' infile
```

Or in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do 
    echo "${line// \+/$'\n'}";
done < infile
```

Or reading to an array and then `printf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -a fields; do
    printf "%s\n" "${fields[@]}";
done < infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i; }' input
```

or if blank lines shall be kept:

```
awk '/^$/ { print; }; { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i; }' input
```

Comment: Why do this approach don't has blank lines, unlike the approach with `fold -1 file`?

Comment: @JohnGoofy I was not sure whether the blank lines were intentional thus I did not care about them. I edited my answer.

Comment: Me too. But I was wondering why awk, respectively your approach, skips blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' <file.in
```

This will replace all spaces in the input file with newlines.

The result will be

```
2
3
4
5
```

(etc.)

To save the output to a file:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' <file.in >file.out
```